# Auto upload in Jquery File Upload not working

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm using [**Jquery File Upload**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload images. Here's my current upload process:

1. click "Add files" button and browse for files
2. click the "Start upload" button and files are uploaded

Everything works fine, but I'm trying to skip point n.2 and upload files automatically when just after browsing. Looking inside documentation, I've found [**this option**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#autoupload) and setup the following snippet:

```
// Load existing files:
$.ajax({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0],
    autoUpload: true
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(this, null, {result: result});
});
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens after file browsing and I still have to press "Start upload" button to begin upload process. What am I missing?

Comment: Try checking any jquery error by using Inspect Element in Google Chrome and Mozilla. May be it is not working just because of an error.

Comment: @anujpradhan unfortunately no errors, but nice suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it out! Since I'm using "jquery.fileupload-ui.js" script, it's sufficient to set (line 51):

`autoUpload: true`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "autoUploade:true" like this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url : '<your upload url>',
        maxFileSize : 20971520,
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(pdf|doc|jpg|xls|tiff|png)$/i
});
```